# How to query more than one tag in Azure Cli

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, restart, azure-cli

I want to query 2 or more tags then use those tags to restart specific VMs as to not restart VMs that doesn't belong to my team.

My current command looks like this. This restarts the VMs with the restart tag = eyes.

```
if [[ $OPTION="start" ]];
then
    VM_IDS=(az resource list --tag Restart=yes --query "[?type=='Microsoft.compute/virtualMachines'].id" -o tsv)
    for id in $VM_IDS
    do
        echo "starting $id"
        az vm start --ids $id --no-wait
    done
fi
```

Comment: So basically you would want all VMs that have one of a given set of tags?

Comment: I want all the VMs that contains at least 2 tags. eg: I want the list of VMs with tags RESTART=yes and TEAM=Cloud. So as to not pull other VMs with only RESTART tag.

Comment: Ahh, so VMs which have both.

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 1):

`--tag` alone won't give you this, it only provides support for a [single tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-list).

> A single tag in 'key[=value]' format. Use "" to clear existing tags.

I would suggest looking at a different solution such as; finding some other way to uniqely identify your VMs, performing two seperate queries and then combining the results, a JMESPath query using an [And expression](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#and-expressions), or simply hardcoding the VM ids into your script.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. Ill look into other options as advised.